# Firefox extension javascript module: what happens to unexported symbols?

Tags: firefox-addon, javascript

I'm just starting to write my first FF extension using javascript modules (rather than trying an XPCOM component) but I'm fuzzy on what happens when a jsm is loaded.

Q: Does the file scope act as a closure for non-exported symbols, or are unreferenced symbols simply garbage collected?

For an example, could/should a module be written as follows?

```
//modules/myModule.js
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = [ 'foo', 'bar' ];

var data;

function foo(){
   return data;
}

function bar(newData){
   data = newData;
}
```

importing it somewhere else as:

```
var aNS = {};
Components.utils.import("resource://myext/myModule.js", aNS);
aNS.bar('it works?');
alert(aNS.foo()); //alert: 'it works?'
```

Even if a module can be written this way, is there a good reason not to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It acts in closure manner, but only if you're referencing it somewhere. In my extension I have something like:

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ['foo'];
let cacheService = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/cache-service;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsICacheService);
let foo = {
   svc : cacheService,
   dosomethingwithit : function(){this.svc.somemethod();}
}
```

So because it is referenced by foo.svc my cacheService is well and alive. If I wasn't referencing it anywhere it would've been garbage collected - which is to no surprise since if it's not used who cares.

But now thinking a bit more about it, I'm just wandering why I did it this way. Doesn't really makes much sense, or difference. I could've had something like:

```
var EXPORTED_SYMBOLS = ['foo'];

function something(){
    this.svc = Components.classes["@mozilla.org/network/cache-service;1"]
                    .getService(Components.interfaces.nsICacheService);
}
let foo = new something();
```

I think I just liked the looks of the first approach more.